# Assignment from Incompatible Pointer Type and Dereferencing Pointer to Incomplete Type

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I was trying to introduce linked lists into my project. I have the general structure down, but I am getting two error's that I cannot wrap my head around. I have "Assignment from incompatible pointer type" and "Dereferencing Pointer to Incomplete Type":

```
ents.c: In function ‘prepend’:
ents.c:13:30: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
             list->head->prev = node;
                              ^
ents.c:14:24: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
             node->next = list->head;
                        ^
ents.c: In function ‘removeEntLink’:
ents.c:22:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     link->prev->next  = link->next;
               ^
ents.c:23:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     link->next->prev = link->prev;

ents.c:53:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
                 node = node->next;
                      ^
```

I googled around and looked through some past stack exchange questions, but generally the problems were people using struct for variable declaration after using typedef, or not putting struct before a member declaration when it refers to itself. However, as far I can tell, this does not seem to be the case in my code.
ents.h:

```
1 #ifndef H_ENTS
2 #define H_ENTS
3 #include <stdlib.h>
4 #include <curses.h>
5 #include "map.h"
6 typedef struct {
7     int y, x, hp;
8     char symbol;
9     struct ent *next;
10     struct ent *prev;
11 }ent;
12 
13 typedef struct {
14     int size;
15     ent *head;
16     ent *tail;
17 } entList;
18 
19 #define ENTS 6
20 extern entList *eList;
21 extern ent *entMap[mapY][mapX];
22 void prepend();
23 void removeEntLink();
24 void initEnt();
25 void drawEnts();
26  
27 #endif
```

and ents.c:

```
1 #include "ents.h"
2 #include "map.h"
3 
4 entList *eList;
5 ent *entMap[mapY][mapX];
6 void prepend(entList *list, ent *node) {
7     if(list) {
8         if(!list->head) {
9             list->head = node;
10             list->tail = node;
11         }   
12         else {
13             list->head->prev = node;
14             node->next = list->head;
15             list->head = node;
16         }   
17         node->prev = NULL;
18         list->size++;
19     }   
20 }   
21 void removeEntLink(ent *link) {
22     link->prev->next  = link->next;
23     link->next->prev = link->prev;
24     link = NULL;
25 }   
26 void initEnt() {
27     eList->size = 0;
28     while(eList->size < ENTS) {
29         ent *ce;
30         do {
31             ce->y = rand() % mapY;
32             ce->x = rand() % mapX;
33         } while (map[ce->y][ce->x] != '.' || entMap[ce->y][ce->x] !=  NULL );
34         if(eList->size == 0) {
35             ce->symbol = '@';
36             ce->hp=10; 
37         }   
38         else {
39             ce->symbol = 'k';
40             ce->hp=3;
41         }   
42         entMap[ce->y][ce->x]=ce;
43         prepend(eList, ce);
44     }   
45 }   
46 // Draw entities
47 void drawEnts() {
48     if(eList) {
49         if(elist->head) {
50             ent *node = elist->head;
51             while(node != NULL) {
52                 mvaddch(node.y, node.x, node.symbol);
53                 node = node->next;
54             }   
55         }   
56     }   
57 
58 }
```

Does anyone know why these issues are arising?

Thanks, Nic

Comment: at define `ent` : `typedef struct {` should be `typedef struct ent {`

Comment: BTW `while (map[ce->y][ce->x] != '.' || entMap[ce->y][ce->x] !=  NULL )` --> `while (map[ce->y][ce->x] != '.' && entMap[ce->y][ce->x] !=  NULL )`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! That worked. But out of curiosity, how come that ent is needed? Also, good catch, thanks.

Comment: `struct ent *next;` : But `struct ent` does not exist.

Comment: when posting code, please do not post the line numbers.   With the line numbers after a copy and paste, we have to edit each line to remove those numbers.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) use meaningful (to the reader) variable names,  Variable names should indicate content or usage (or better both). For instance, what is an 'ent' ? and how does that become a 'ec'?   Those names are meaningless to the reader of the code

Answer (score 0):

You have written:

```
struct ent *next;
```

however, your program does not contain a type called `struct ent`. (It does have a type `ent`, but that's not the same thing).

You could change line 6 to call the type `struct ent`:

typedef struct ent {
      ...
   } ent;

- notice that this makes `struct ent` and `ent` two different names for the same type.